# I can't resize partition with GParted

Tags: ubuntu, partition, gparted

I tried to resize my partition with GParted. But I can't resize the **ext4** partition.
I tried to look at other question on this site, but it doesn't seem like I can find the solution.

[image: Capture GParted]

The **ext4** partition is on `/dev/sda6`. When I try to resize it, I can't change the size.

[image: Capture GParted, can't change size]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your partition is locked as indicated by the key
symbol, because `/` is currently mounted. You can boot from a Linux Live USB and run GParted from there or boot a [GParted Live CD/USB](https://gparted.org/download.php) to resize your partition.

Comment: Ah, I see, the other user asked the same question as me but he was in a VM. Thank you I'll try that.

Comment: The Gparted solution was pretty easy to me.  This video might be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fteij2amMos