# Can't increase Virtual Machine partition with GParted

Tags: partition, virtualbox, virtual-machine, gparted

I have a Ubuntu virtual machine on VirtualBox on a Windows host operating system. I want to increase the available disk space on the virtual machine.

I tried following [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/124622/how-to-enlarge-a-virtual-machines-disk-in-virtualbox-or-vmware/#:%7E:text=To%20access%20it%2C%20click%20File,%E2%80%9D%20when%20you%27re%20done.) but I can't make the final resizing of the partition.

I first increased the disk space of the virtual machine from 20 GB to 40 GB.

[image: img]

I then ran the command on the command prompt.

[image]

Then I added a bootable iso image of GParted on the virtual optical disk and booted into GParted. From GParted I can see the unused disk space on the right of my partition, but when I try to resize the partition I do not have the option to increase it, I can only shrink it.

[image]

Does anybody know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sda5` is inside the `sda2` extended partition container. This is a necessary artifact of MBR partition tables when you might want to have more than four partitions.

1. Extend `sda2` (the "extended" partition)
2. Extend `sda5` (the ext4 partition)
3. Extend the filesystem on `sda5` (`resize2fs /dev/sda5`)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue for:

- Host macOS
- Guest `Ubuntu Desktop` 22.04

The **procedure** for other Host with Windows 10 and with the same Guest was:

- expand first the `extended` partition
- expand second  the `ext4` partition

It because the former contains the latter.

**But** in this situation - with a slight variation - I got an error message indicating that the `ext4` partition is *read-only* (btw the *extended* partition was resized in peace)

It *seems* according with this post:

- [I can't resize partition with GParted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/612706/383045)

Because the `ext4` partition contains `\` and it is mounted therefore is not possible accomplish the resize goal - **but** as I indicated: in the other Host with the same guest the procedure was accomplished successfully - **even** when the `ext4` partition contains `\` and it is mounted too.

Well the other post is not related with `VirtualBox`, but the solution is correct:

- Boot a `GParted Live CD/USB`.

Therefore for our case working with `VirtualBox`

### Solution

- Shutdown your VM
- Download the GParted `.iso` file from its homepage.
- Select your VM
- Open Settings
- Select Storage
- At `Controller IDE` the CD must be empty.
- Select `empty`, and in the right, at `Attributes` do click in the `cd` icon
- Through the `Choose a disk file` item proceed to select the downloaded GParted `.iso` file.
- Check the `Live CD/DVD` checkbox
- Press `OK` button
- Start the VM

Now GParted is loaded and the `ext4` partition can be resized to fit with the same size of the `extended` partition. It worked in my side.

Once accomplished all the process, is straightforward remove the GParted `.iso` file.

Comment: I followed instructions above on a Windows guest, with an Oracle VirtualBox machine hosting a LightUbuntu system, and I solved my issue of having low disk space for the device holding the root files system. Thank you.

Comment: @luisarosi you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just saw your question now, and I will try my best to help you.

You know,

Principle-A: Size(vm_disk) == Size(primary/main partition) + Size(extended partition);

Principle-B: Size(extended partition) == All of the Size(logical partition);

Principle-C: Size(logical partiton) <= Size(extended parition);

As your `GParted` show, the primary/main partition is `/dev/sda1`; the extended partition is `/dev/sda2`; and logical partition is `/dev/sda5`.

If you want to expand logical partition`/dev/sda5`, firstly, you should expand extended parition `/dev/sda2` because priciple-C, and if you just use `sudo cfdisk -l` to check the usage of all your partition on yout VM's terminal, I guess your VM's terminal show below:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 40 GiB, 42212254720 bytes, 82914560 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x50c8fe86

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *           1     512M  1102880  512M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda2           512M      20G 39902880 19.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5           512M      20G 39902880 19.5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
free space           20G      40G 41162880   20G
```

Also, I guess you want to get below output via `sudo cfdisk` after you expand the logical partition `/dev/sda5`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 40 GiB, 42212254720 bytes, 82914560 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x50c8fe86

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *           1     512M  1102880  512M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda2           512M      40G 81066760 39.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5           512M      40G 81066760 39.5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

So the solution is clear. I do highly recommend you use `cfdisk` instead of ISO APP`GParted`. Also, just use `cfdisk` for an example.

Solution:

1.please log in your VM via terminal;

2.use `sudo cfdisk` to enter the permission of `cfdisk`;

Just use `up` and `down` direction button to choose the target partition, use `right` and `left` direction button to choose the `cfdisk` operation, use `enter` button to make sure.

3.use the `Resize` button of `cfdisk` to expand the extended partition `/dev/sda2`, clean the default disk size and input `39.5GB`, then ok;

4.use the `Resize` button of `cfdisk` to expand the logical partition `/dev/sda5`, also, clean the default disk size and input `39.5GB`, then ok;

5.use the `Write` button of `cfdisk` to write the operation to the Disk, then use `Quit` button to quit `cfdisk`;

6.Set all of the expanded logical partition `/dev/sda5` into `ext4` via `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda5`;

7.Restart or reboot your virtual machine: `sudo reboot`.

Have fun!!!

OVER!

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize the top level (empty top level) first sda2 extented, then resize again your partition containing data.

Comment: Please note that your answer seems to reiterate what was already stated in the [@roaima's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/692911/377345). You may want to consider expanding it so that the difference to that answer becomes more visible; otherwise it would be best placed as a comment to that answer (once you have sufficient reputation).